# Sharing common folder in OS Mavericks and on Windows 8?

Tags: macos, mac, permission, error, sharing

I have many PCs with **Windows 8.1** and a Mac with **Mavericks**. I have a folder on the Mac that is shared with the PC. "*Share*" folder which is shared over network .
I want help regarding this :

1) I want to share this folder to Windows 8.1. with the guest user so that I don't have to create a new user for sharing, and also give the password and username to every user who is going to be connected to my network.

2) Secondly , I want this folder have *Read & Write* permission over network so that anyone can write and read to this folder.

I am able to view the folder in Windows with the username and password, but when I try to write some data to shared folder in Windows, I am not able to access the written data in the Mac. I get the permission issue `"You don't have permission to read this data."`

I am very new to Mac and help would be appreciated.

I followed this guide.

http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/08/share-files-from-mac-to-windows-pc/

Comment: If you don't "need" direct share, iCloud Documents works great for me. Also, Dropbox is something many people use. Hopefully the direct answers meet your needs, but if not, there are dozens of "shared folder" implementations and even transporter hardware for huge shared folders on a semi-private cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're having [this problem](http://blog.rubbingalcoholic.com/post/39412902216/fix-smb-windows-sharing-permissions-issue-in-os-x-10-7). You will need to install the real Samba, not Apple's version of SMB. It might be easier to put the SMB share on one of your Windows machines, though I don't know how that will go on Windows 8.